# custom Allocator compilation difficulties

Tags: c++, c++11, allocator

I am trying to create a custom allocator, but there are compilation problems. 
By changing the value of the define from

```
#define _GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING 0
```

to

```
#define _GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING 1
```

I managed to switch from being unable to compile to being able to compile, but should it be like that? Shouldn't it be a little bit simpler ?

Does any body has experienc on that and already knows how these compilation problems may be solved.

The code the minimal required:

```
#include <bits/c++config.h>
#define _GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING 0

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <limits>


typedef int32_t Token;
typedef unsigned char byte;

using namespace std;
template <typename T>
struct Allocator {
 public:
    static const size_t heapSize=0x1000;
    static size_t freePos;
    static Token freeT;
    static byte m[heapSize];

// http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4795/C-Standard-Allocator-An-Introduction-and-Implement

    typedef T value_type;

    typedef value_type* pointer;typedef const value_type* const_pointer;

    typedef value_type& reference;typedef const value_type& const_reference;

    typedef std::size_t size_type;
  typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;

  template<typename U> struct rebind {typedef Allocator<U> other;};

    inline explicit Allocator() {freeT=0;freePos=0;}
  inline ~Allocator() {}
  inline Allocator(Allocator const&) {} // with explicit it doesn't compile

    //template<typename U>
  //inline explicit Allocator(Allocator<U> const&) {}

  inline pointer address(reference r) {return &r;}
  inline const_pointer address(const_reference r) {return &r;}

  static inline pointer allocate(size_type cnt, typename std::allocator<void>::const_pointer hint = 0){ 
        return reinterpret_cast<pointer>(::operator new(cnt * sizeof (T))); 
/*  pointer allocate(size_type n, const_pointer hint = 0 ){
        size_t t=freePos;freePos+=sizeof(T)*n;return t;
    }
*/
  }

    static inline void deallocate(pointer p, size_type){
        ::operator delete(p);
/*  pointer deallocate(pointer p,size_type n){
        size_t sz=sizeof(T)*n;
        *(size_t*)(m+p)=sz;
    }
*/
    }

  inline size_type max_size() const{ 
        return std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max() / sizeof(T);
    }
  inline void construct(pointer p, const T& t) { new(p) T(t); }

/*
  void              construct(pointer p, const T& val) 
                    { new ((T*) p) T(val); }
*/
  inline void destroy(pointer p) { p->~T(); }
//   void              destroy(pointer p) { ((T*)m[p])->~T(); }

  inline bool operator==(Allocator const&) {return true;}
  inline bool operator!=(Allocator const& a) {return false;}
};

#endif


using namespace std;

typedef     std::basic_string< char,std::char_traits<char>,Allocator<char> > String;

int main(){
String s("Nice-the-data-goes-in-my-memory");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "But there are compilation problems"... is this a trick question? Are you recruiting for Google and want to see who can debug mystery meat fastest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine if you make the comparison operators free functions. In general, relational operators should be free functions so they can convert implicitly on both sides:

```
template <typename T>
bool operator==(Allocator<T> const &, Allocator<T> const &) { return true; }

template <typename T>
bool operator!=(Allocator<T> const &, Allocator<T> const &) { return false; }
```

Comment: If I was recruiting I would had. Thanks, but I should understand why !?! with a little bit more words.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis: As I said, implicit conversions. You want to be able to say `a == b` as soon as `a` and `b` are *convertible* to your type. With a member function, `a` would exactly have to be your type.

Comment: What about the next question "custom Allocator compilation difficulties 2" and how could I avoid to ask ? It seems ultra complicated to debug that code !

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis: Don't program by guessing. Read up on allocator requirements and be methodical.